# Getting Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch using .Find

Tags: excel, vba

The part of the code giving me the error is borrowed from research on how to find a specific value, match it to a value on another worksheet and delete that row of data. The code has multi tasks to complete:

1. Copy the row on sheet22 and paste it to the next empty row on
   sheet13
2. Find a match to Sheet22 cell C2 on Sheet 11 column A and
   delete the matching row on sheet 11
3. Add formulas into columns F:M &
   Q on row 2 of sheet22

   ```
   Sub LineArchive_DD118()

   Dim TMLastDistRow
   Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
   Dim LastRowInRange As Long, RowCounter As Long

   TMLastDistRow = Worksheets("Trailer Archives").Cells(Sheet13.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   LastRowInRange = Sheets(Sheet11).Range("A:A").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row ' Returns a Row Number

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   If Sheets("Dock Door Status").Range("P2").Value = "F" Then
       With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
           .Range("P2").Value = "F"
           .Range("C2:R2").Copy
       End With

       With Sheets("Trailer Archives")
           .Range("B" & TMLastDistRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
       End With

   Else
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear DD118?", vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Dock Door 118 Data")
   If Answer = vbYes Then

       For RowCounter = LastRowInRange To 1 Step -1 ' Count Backwards
           If Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A" & RowCounter) = Sheets("Sheet22").Range("C2") Then '   If Cell matches our 'Delete if' value then
               Sheets("Sheet11").Rows(RowCounter).EntireRow.Delete '       Delete the row
           End If
       Next

       With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
           .Range("D2:Q2").ClearContents
           .Range("D2") = "CLOSED"
       End With

       With Sheets("Dock Door Status")
           .Range("F2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!B$2:B$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("G2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!C$2:C$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("H2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!D$2:D$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("I2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!E$2:E$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("J2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!F$2:F$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("K2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!G$2:G$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("L2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!H$2:H$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("M2").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('SSP Data'!I$2:I$50,MATCH($C2,'SSP Data'!$A$2:$A$50,0)),"""")"
           .Range("Q2").Formula = "=IF(G2="""","""",IF(AND(M2="""",N2>G2),""Future"",""Current""))"
       End With

   Else
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
   ```

The line that is throwing the error is:

```
LastRowInRange = Sheets(Sheet11).Range("A:A").Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row ' Returns a Row Number
```

I think that part of it is I would like to replace the wildcard with a static text string, i.e. "*" with "DD118". I am sure there is more to the error than that.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Sheets(Sheet11).... -> Sheet11...

Comment: uh, Sheets(Sheet11) ... -> Sheets("Sheet11")..

Comment: Ok. I changed Sheets(Sheet11) to Sheet 11 and then received Error 9 on this line:      If Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A" & RowCounter) = Sheets("Sheet22").Range("C2") Then '   If Cell matches our 'Delete if' value then. Should I make similar changes?

Comment: @user3598756 Update. Made the change (Sheets(Sheet11).... -> Sheet11) on all lines and it worked. Thank you.